# How to copy * char to static array of strings, printf producing strange output,

Tags: c, arrays, char

I've tried various permutations of this type of loop.

```
char hrstdesc[50][50];
char hrstread[50][50];
int i = 0;

for (hfree = hentry; hfree; hfree = hfree->prev) {
    if (filterentry(hfree)) {
        continue;
    }

    strcpy(&hrstdesc[i][0], hfree->hrstdesc);
    printf("%s \n", hrstdesc[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("%s \n", hrstdesc[1]);
```

The output is,

```
/run/media/username/archive
/home
/var
/
/ho/va/
```

The first 4 lines come from, `printf("%s \n", srtdesc);`, and are what I'd expect.

The last line, i'd expect to see `/home`, but instead I get `/ho/va/`.

https://github.com/techzilla/check_snmp_extras/blob/master/src/check_snmp_disk.c

Comment: for (hentry = hentry; ) ???

Comment: `hentry = hentry` why would you even do that?

Comment: @babon, please correct me, I'd appreciate it immensely.  I just thought that's what you were supposed to do when looping over this struct.   I'm very interested in better practice.

I've seen some people make a temp variable, to run such a loop, but wasn't sure why. somewhat like, `for (hfree = hentry; hfree; hfree = hfree->prev) {`

Comment: The `=` operator takes whatever is in the right side and assigns it to the variable on the left side. Since both your variables on the right and left are same, you are reading from the same variable as the one you are writing to. Thus achieving nothing. BTW, the code in your comment does not match with the one you originally posted.

Comment: @babon, Do people do the temp variable version to maintain the original pointer once the loop ends?  I know it doesn't, I'll fix the post with it.

Comment: Forget about what "people do". Think what you want to achieve. Read about the `for` loop in C.

Comment: @babon, well, what I want to achieve is printing the string I'm attempting to copy to the array.  I read plenty of intro books, and the book with the GNU on it, and I wrote something else prior.  What the books don't teach you is best practices, like how professional programmers write maintainable code.  For all your effort, you'd think you'd take a shot at the problem I actually have.  I mean, so what if the for loop was essential noop'd like a while, this is an ugly first draft.  Though because of  your response, I corrected it anyway with what I knew before I posted this question.

Comment: BTW, ignore the return value of strcpy()

Comment: @BjornA., Thank you Bjorn, I very much appreciate the tip.

Comment: Show us the full program for a start.

Comment: The problem is how `hfree->hrstdesc` is assigned.  Need to see `filterentry()` and `hfree` definition.

Comment: Repo link to source has been added,

Comment: it would be interesting to add additional `printf()` after the loop to print out `hrstdesc[0]` and `hrstdesc[2]` in addition to `hrstdesc[1]`. I am curious what that output would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file you linked, you're defining hrstdesc[][] as hrstdesc[MAX_ENTRIES][MAX_ENTRIES] (not [50][50]).  MAX_ENTRIES is #defined as 3 in the check_snmp_extras.h header available in same repo.

The weird behavior is due to an overrun of hrstdesc[][] on each loop iteration.

Your final hrstdesc[1] is the first 3 characters from loop iteration 1 (/home), followed by the first 3 characters from loop iteration 2 (/var), followed by the one character from loop iteration 3 (/).

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get some kind of segmentation fault or core dump, etc due to corrupted memory...